# How do I put subscripts on referenced items with enumitem?

Tags: typography, enumitem

I have an enumerated list with the labels in parentheses.  I want to reuse a label using \ref but with a prime symbol or a subscript.  How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\arabic*)}}  

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first sentence.
\item\label{toprime} I will give a variant of this sentence soon.
\end{enumerate}

Now here's some intervening material.

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Let's stick another sentence in.
\item[\ref{toprime}$'$] I am now giving a variant of the original
  sentence.
\item[\ref{toprime}$_2$] I would also like to tack on subscripts.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

I want the prime symbol and the subscript to appear inside the parentheses.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ref` to set a reference format distinct from `label`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\arabic*)},ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first sentence.
\item\label{toprime} I will give a variant of this sentence soon.
\end{enumerate}

Now here's some intervening material.

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Let's stick another sentence in.
\item[(\ref{toprime}$'$)] I am now giving a variant of the original
  sentence.
\item[(\ref{toprime}$_2$)] I would also like to tack on subscripts.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy variations]

Comment: Thank you.  That helps.  But what do I do if for the rest of the paper I want my references to appear in parentheses without having to do    (\ref{toprime})?

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried this right away.  The \setlist command can occur outside of the preamble, and be changed temporarily within a given enumerate environment.  So my preceding comment can be ignored.

Comment: @Ruby Oh, yes. Sorry. I forgot about your earlier comment. (I couldn't reply when I read it initially and I wasn't sure quite what you wanted.) I'm glad you sorted it. Yes, you can use `\setlist` and `\newlist` within the document. And you can change the format of a list multiple times, if necessary. Though it might make for confusing code.

Comment: I was actually thinking of suggesting something like `fancyref` or `cleverref` which can format references depending on context and content. But probably not worth it unless you have a use for them anyway.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  What I said worked didn't actually work.